# Converting cv::mat to System::Object

Tags: c++, windows, winforms, opencv, c++-cli

I have an application where I need to pass a cv::Mat into a Windows Form to be displayed on a PictureBox control.  The cv::Mat is being passed into the Form from a separate thread from the one that the Form resides in.  I have used the thread-safe method below for passing information into Forms from other threads quite often, but it has always been reference types that I have passed.  Here's what I'm trying to accomplish, but the cv::Mat can't be converted to a System::Object:

```
class Reader
{
    delegate void ReceiveFrameDelegate(cv::Mat frame, Field field, bool bIsRecording);

    void receiveFrame(cv::Mat frame, Field field, bool bIsRecording)
    {
        //InvokeRequired compares the thread ID of the  
        //calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.  
        //If these threads are different, it returns true.  
        if (this->InvokeRequired)
        {
            ReceiveFrameDelegate^ d = gcnew ReceiveFrameDelegate(this, &Reader::receiveFrame);
            array<System::Object^>^myArray = gcnew array<System::Object^>(3);
            myArray[0] = frame;     // Compile fails: No type conversion exists for cv::Mat
            myArray[1] = field;
            myArray[2] = bIsRecording;
            this->Invoke(d, myArray);
        }
        else
        {
            // Do what needs to be done
            ....
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to cast a cv::Mat to a System::Object? Can I cast a cv::Mat to a reference type and then to a System::Object?  Since cv::Mat is not inherited from System::Object, I'm not sure how to do this.  Is there another thread-safe way to pass a cv::Mat from another thread?  Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can go via bitmap to System::Object, so - Possible duplicate of [Error C2440 : cannot cast 'System::Drawing::Bitmap' into 'System::Object'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44693891/error-c2440-cannot-cast-systemdrawingbitmap-into-systemobject)

Comment: Thanks for looking at this, but System::Drawing::Bitmap is inherited from System::Object, but cv::Mat is not.

Comment: That link provides a set of functions in PluginCV.h to convert the datatype from cv::Mat to System::Drawing::Bitmap